# Invoking child nodes Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm new into this sort of object programming, do you mind helping me?

I have to invoke the child nodes, but specific fields, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have already looked into a huge number of places, but it doesn't seem to work.

For example, I want just the `FirstName` in the `RepunicAccount`, and all the other info from `RepunicAccountType`, or anything like it.

My `DbContext`:

```
public class RepunicContext : DbContext 
{
    public virtual DbSet<RepunicAccount> RepunicAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<RepunicAccountType> RepunicAccountType { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) 
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer ("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=Repunic;Data Source=DESKTOP-        6I8LD45\\SQLEXPRESS_ERICH");
    }

    public RepunicContext (DbContextOptions<RepunicContext> options) :base (options)
    { }

    public RepunicContext () { }
}
```

My model class:

```
public class RepunicAccount 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey ("ID_Type")]
    public int? ID_Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<RepunicAccountType> TipoConta { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime? DataAlteracao { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

My child node class:

```
public class RepunicAccountType 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Type { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime DataAlteracao { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

I have a repository, that is where I do my coding, before putting into the controller, it's pretty much the same in every place, but I'm going to show the example that I'm trying to use in both places.

```
public IEnumerable<RepunicAccount> GetAllByIDType () 
{
    var data = db.RepunicAccount.Where (a => a.ID_Type != null)
                                .Include (p => p.types);
    var type = db.RepunicAccountType.OrderBy (b => b.Descricao);

    return data.ToList();
}
```

The problem is: I don`t know how to invoke specific items nor make anything else other than`ToList();`

So, what should I do? If there is any more info that I can send, just ask me.

Comment: Do you have controllers and views associated with this code? What are you target Web or Desktop?

Comment: Have you tried `.Select`?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to comment however, I do not have the required reputation to do so.

Since you are new to the subject please be sure to follow the documentation.

[EF Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)

I also have created a youtube video for getting started that I would suggest you take a few minutes to view.

[Video on EF Core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NP_-XB9ltqA)

in short, you need a DBContext and your Models. You then can start a query for data and returning in the format you wish. Like so:

```
    using (var context = new RepunicContext())
      {
        var accounts = context.RepunicAccounts.ToList();
      }
```

accounts will then have a list of every account that you can iterate through. Hope this helps.